# How to mock moment.utc() for unit tests?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, momentjs

I'm just starting out with Node and I'm now writing some unit tests. For the first couple functions I have that works ok, but I now hit upon a function which includes `moment.utc()` in it. A simplified version of my function looks like this:

```
function calculate_x(positions, risk_free_interest){
    let x = 0;
    for (let position of positions) {
        let expiry_in_years = get_expire_in_years(moment.utc());
        if (expiry_in_years > 0){
            let pos_x = tools.get_x(expiry_in_years, risk_free_interest);
            x += pos_x;
        }
    }

    return x;
}
```

I try to test this using the basic node assert testing lib:

```
"use strict";
const assert = require('assert');
let positions = [{this: 'is', a: 'very', large: 'object'}]; 
assert.strictEqual(calculate_x(positions, 1.8), 1.5);
```

Since the times at which this is run (and thus the result) will always be different this will always fail.

In Python I can set mock classes and objects. Is there a way that I can solve this problem in Node without giving the moment.utc() as an argument to the `calculate_x()` function?

Comment: Do you need something like [Changing Time Source](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/now/)?

Comment: sinon is a great test library esp for node, you can mock/alter timers in there as well http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.0.1/fake-timers/

Comment: @VincenzoC - Awesome! Exactly what I needed! If you add your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @kramer65 ok, I'll put it into an answer :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Moment lets you [Change Time Source](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/now/)

> If you want to change the time that Moment sees, you can specify a method that returns the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (January 1, 1970).
>
> The default is:
>
> ```
> moment.now = function () {
>     return +new Date();
> }
> ```
>
> This will be used when calling `moment()`, and the current date used when tokens are omitted from `format()`. In general, any method that needs the current time uses this under the hood.

So you can redefine `moment.now` to get the custom output when you code executes `moment.utc()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
const moment = require('moment'); 
const time = moment().valueOf();
moment.now = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(time);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to override the utc function and nothing else is working, try adding this in your test suite

```
moment.prototype.utc = sinon.stub().callsFake(() => new Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0));
```

or

```
moment.prototype.utc = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(new Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0));
```