# Jest testing/mocking Moment in React Native

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, momentjs, jestjs

I am trying to make some tests for my React Native component that uses moment.js for a datepicker. I am having trouble testing/mocking moment.js and was wondering if I could get any examples/pointers. The two functions I am trying to test are below:

```js
setDate = (newDate) => {
    this.setState({ selectedDate: moment(newDate) });
}

handleOnPress = () => {
    this.props.onModalButtonPress(this.state.selectedDate.unix());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock moment.utc() for unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891897/how-to-mock-moment-utc-for-unit-tests)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to put in the `__mocks__` folder (next to the test file) the mocked `moment.js` with following content (manual mocking):

```js
const moment = require.requireActual('moment');

export default (timestamp=0) => {
    return moment(timestamp);
}
```

Then Jest will use it in your test. Above will assure that calling `moment()` will return the same time. Which then helps in test comparisons.

If you are using some static methods like `weekdaysShort` then you will need to modify the mock to include this (And any other you might have used):

```js
const moment = require.requireActual('moment');

const mockedMoment = (timestamp=0) => {
    return moment(timestamp);
};
mockedMoment.weekdaysShort = () => [
    "Sun",
    "Mon",
    "Tue",
    "Wed",
    "Thu",
    "Fri",
    "Sat",
];
export default mockedMoment;
```