# Mocking moment() and moment().format using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, momentjs

I'm unable to mock `moment()` or `moment().format` functions. I have states where, `currentDateMoment` and `currentDateFormatted` are getting set as below.

```
currentDateMoment: moment() //2019-04-23T17:45:26.339Z
currentDateFormatted: moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY').valueOf() //"04-23-2019"
```

Trying to mock both `moment()` and `moment().format` in my snapshot tests to return a particular date, but was unable to. Tried below.

```
jest.mock('moment', () => () => '2018–01–30T12:34:56+00:00');

jest.mock('moment', () => ({
  constructor: () => '2018–01–30T12:34:56+00:00'
})); 

jest.mock('moment', () => () => ({ format: () => '01–30-2018' }));
```

Comment: This seems like a strange thing to be mocking, why do you need to inject a particular date to perform your testing?

Comment: I have a snapshot test and need to mock moment() to return a certain date to not have it fail the next day...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock moment.utc() for unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891897/how-to-mock-moment-utc-for-unit-tests)

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Any update?

Comment: Similar issue in the code base. Do we have a fix for this yet?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65130857/3001761. Don't mock things (`moment`, `Date`) you don't own, and treat time as a *dependency*.

Comment: Do you have any ideas for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68209029/jest-mock-moment-to-return-specific-date

Answer (score 69):

The easiest way to mock moment() and any function that it uses (i.e. `.day()`, `.format()`) is to change the `Date` that `moment()` uses under the hood

Add the snippet below inside your test file

`Date.now = jest.fn(() => new Date("2020-05-13T12:33:37.000Z"));`

This makes it so anytime `moment()` is called in your tests, `moment()` thinks that today is Wednesday, May 13th 2020

Comment: Yes, I like this too, it's simple to setup. I personally like using it this way: ```Date.now = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(new Date('2020-05-13T12:33:37.000Z'));```

Comment: I successfully used `jest.spyOn(Date, 'now').mockImplementation(...)`

Comment: it does not work on my case, moment() return null after I mock like this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68209029/jest-mock-moment-to-return-specific-date

Comment: I use this on react-native `const mockNowDate = (date: string) =>
  (global.Date.now = jest.fn(() => new Date(date).getTime()));` and rollback to the real one afterAll test `afterAll(() => { global.Date = RealDate;});`

Comment: Neat, in Typescript remember to add: `Date.now = jest.fn(() => new Date('2020-11-01T12:33:37.000Z').getTime());`

Comment: If moment will change implementation in some way this will break all the tests that relay on this

Answer (score 34):

You can mock Moment to return a specific date, then `format` don't have to be mocked.

```js
jest.mock('moment', () => {
  return () => jest.requireActual('moment')('2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z');
});
```

By doing so, any call to `Moment()` will always return a moment object with date set to **2020-01-01 00:00:00**

Here is an example with a function that return the date of tomorrow and the test for this function.

```
const moment = require('moment');
const tomorrow = () => {
  const now = moment();
  return now.add(1, 'days');
};

describe('tomorrow', () => {
  it('should return the next day in a specific format', () => {
    const date = tomorrow().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    expect(date).toEqual('2020-01-02');
  });
});
```

Comment: do you have any ideas about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68209029/jest-mock-moment-to-return-specific-date

Answer (score 8):

Here is the solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
import moment from 'moment';

export function main() {
  return {
    currentDateMoment: moment().format(),
    currentDateFormatted: moment()
      .format('MM-DD-YYYY')
      .valueOf()
  };
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { main } from './';
import moment from 'moment';

jest.mock('moment', () => {
  const mMoment = {
    format: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    valueOf: jest.fn()
  };
  return jest.fn(() => mMoment);
});

describe('main', () => {
  test('should mock moment() and moment().format() correctly ', () => {
    (moment().format as jest.MockedFunction<any>)
      .mockReturnValueOnce('2018–01–30T12:34:56+00:00')
      .mockReturnValueOnce('01–30-2018');
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(moment)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(moment().format)).toBeTruthy();
    const actualValue = main();
    expect(actualValue).toEqual({ currentDateMoment: '2018–01–30T12:34:56+00:00', currentDateFormatted: '01–30-2018' });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/55838798/index.spec.ts
  main
    ✓ should mock moment() and moment().format() correctly  (7ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.795s, estimated 8s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/55838798

Comment: Did not work for me unfortunately in my js test case. I am importing moment as-> import * as moment from 'moment';

Comment: This is a good example of why you _shouldn't_ mock moment, this is _so_ coupled to the implementation.

Answer (score 5):

[mockdate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockdate) works for me

```
import mockDate from "mockdate";


test('Should add some', () => {
    mockDate.set(new Date('2/20/2020'));

    const action = addSome();

    expect(action).toEqual({
        createdAt: moment()
    });

    mockDate.reset();
})
```

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**
Found [testing moment with jest](https://terodox.tech/testing-moment-with-jest/) and it really helped me with my solution.

**Context**
I needed to mock format with the moment-timezone so here is my solution and ran into issues where `moment`, `format` or other methods within the `moment` function were not defined.

**Solution**

```
// mock the module using automock from jest
jest.mock('moment-timezone', () => {
    // mocking a module requires the function definitions, to only partially mock, use requireActual 

    const moment = jest.requireActual('moment-timezone');
    // create a momentInstance
    const momentInstance = moment();

    // Override the format function with some mockedTime
    jest.spyOn(momentInstance, 'format').mockImplementation(() => mockedTime);

    function fakeMoment() {
        return momentInstance;
    }

    Object.assign(fakeMoment, moment);

    return fakeMoment;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers tell you how to mock moment, but you don't *need* to mock moment to test that code. You probably shouldn't, in fact; it's a complicated third party interface you don't own and mocking it couples your tests to it, you end up testing *implementation* rather than *behaviour*.

Rather than calling `moment()` without any arguments, call it with the current date (per https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/01-parsing/01-now/ `moment()` is basically `moment(new Date())`). Then that current date comes from a function you *do* own:

```
const { getCurrentDate } = require('path/to/utils');

export const createSomething =() => ({
  currentDateMoment: moment(getCurrentDate()),
  currentDateFormatted: moment(getCurrentDate()).format('MM-DD-YYYY'),
});
```

so you can trivially mock that out in the tests:

```
const { createSomething } = require('path/to/impl');
const { getCurrentDate } = require('path/to/utils');
jest.mock('path/to/utils');

it('formats the data correctly', () => {
  getCurrentDate.mockReturnValue(new Date(2021, 3, 29));

  const { currentDateFormatted } = createSomething();
  expect(currentDateFormatted).toEqual('2021-04-29');
});
```

Now the test doesn't refer to moment, which has become an implementation detail, at all. If there's a breaking future change to the moment API you'll find out about it, because your tests will fail; they'd misleadingly pass if it was mocked. If you want to switch to a different library you can do so, confident that the tests mean the *behaviour* is still correct ([here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65130857/3001761) an example doing the same thing with DayJS).

Answer (score 1):

To Mock `Moment().format()`,`startOf()` , `isValid()` or `isAfter()` etc. Can refer below example.

```
jest.mock('moment', () => {
    
    const momentParams = {
        format: jest.fn(() => '10/04/2020'),
        startOf: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        isAfter: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true),
        isValid: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true)
    };

   const fn = jest.fn(newMoment => {
        momentParams.format = jest.fn(() => newMoment);
        return momentParams;
   });

   return fn;
});
```

And last you can write a test case like this.
eg.

```
 test('should returned mocked value for isAfter()', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(moment(), 'isAfter').mockReturnValue(false);
    const response = moment().isAfter();
    expect(response).toBe(false)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was still getting some errors because I was using moment-timezone, too. So, here's what I did to fix that:

```js
let diffMins = updateThreshold + 1;
jest.mock('moment', () => {
  const mMoment = {
    diff: jest.fn(() => diffMins),
  };
  const fn = jest.fn(() => mMoment);
  fn.version = '2.24';
  fn.tz = jest.fn();
  fn.fn = jest.fn();
  return fn;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have followed above post and have some errors because only mock some functions instead of moment object time.

Changed a little bit as below

```
jest.mock('moment-timezone', () => {
   const moment = require('moment');
   // Mock to the date you want
   return moment.utc('2023-01-01 08:30:40')
}
```

Follow this config, the test function worked as expectation and don't have the error: unix method is null, format method is undefined etc