# Mock using jest moment().format is returning current date instead of mocked date

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs, moment-timezone

I am trying to mock moment library's format function using jest. I have following code in my test file.

**app.spec.js**:

```
jest.mock('moment', () => {
    const moment = () => ({
        format: () => mockedTime
    });
    moment.tz = {
        setDefault: () => {}
    };
    moment.tz.setDefault('Asia/Singapore');
    return moment;
});
```

**app.js**:

```
moment.tz.setDefault(TIMEZONE);
moment().format('YYYYMMDD');
```

it is generating following output:

```
 - "date": "20190825", // mocked date
 - "date": "20190827", // result value
```

the expected output should be:

```
 - "date": "20190825", // mocked date
 - "date": "20190825", // result value
```

Can anyone help me point out what's wrong with the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55838798/mocking-moment-and-moment-format-using-jest

Comment: why do you use `doMock`in favor of `.mock`? first one does not affect code been already `import`ed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mocking 'moment-timezone' instead of 'moment fixed it.

```
jest.mock('moment-timezone', () => {
    const moment = () => ({
        format: () => mockedTime
    });
    moment.tz = {
        setDefault: () => {}
    };
    moment.tz.setDefault('Asia/Singapore');
    return moment;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The available answers did not work for my case. Mocking the underlying `Date.now` function however did as this answer suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61659370/6502003

```js
Date.now = jest.fn(() => new Date('2020-05-13T12:33:37.000Z'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `format` not on `moment`, but on the result of `moment()`.

```js
    jest.doMock('moment', () => {
        const moment = () => ({
            format: () => mockedTime,
        })

        moment.tz = { // prevent 'Cannot read property of undefined'
            setDefault: () => {},
        }

        return moment
    });
```

Is this OK, or do you need more complicated mock in you app, including timezone?

Comment: i need timezone included

Comment: It throws a `typeError: can not read property 'split' of undefined`

Comment: If you have another operation on `moment` you should also mock other methods used. Since you shared only small part and not a working snippet, it's hard to debug.