# Mocking dayjs extend

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, dayjs

In my code that needs testing I use

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';
dayjs.extend(utc);

dayjs().add(15, 'minute')
```

In my test I need to mock dayjs in order to always have the same date when comparing snapshots in `jest` so I did

```
jest.mock('dayjs', () =>
  jest.fn((...args) =>
    jest.requireActual('dayjs')(
      args.filter((arg) => arg).length > 0 ? args : '2020-08-12'
    )
  )
);
```

It fails with

```
TypeError: _dayjs.default.extend is not a function
```

Unfortunately similar questions on here didn't help me. How could I mock both default `dayjs` but also `extend`?

Comment: Try not to mock dayjs, you don't own that interface. Treat time as a dependency, so you can mock out your own module that returns a Date - then use `dayjs(yourFunction())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* write a more thorough manual mock for `dayjs`, one that has the `extend` method, but then you're coupling your tests to a 3rd party interface. *"Don't mock what you don't own"* - you'll end up having to recreate more and more of the `dayjs` interface in your mock, and then if that interface changes your tests will continue to pass but *your code will be broken*. Or if you decide to swap to a different time library, you have to rewrite all of your tests to manually mock the new interface.

Instead, treat time as a dependency. Have your own function, in your own module, that simply provides the current time as a `Date` object:

```js
export const howSoonIsNow = () => new Date();
```

Then, when you need to create a `dayjs` object, do so *from that* (`dayjs()` is equivalent to `dayjs(new Date())` per [the docs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/now)):

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';

import { howSoonIsNow } from './path/to/noTimeLikeThePresent';

dayjs.extend(utc);

dayjs(howSoonIsNow()).add(15, 'minute');
```

Now in your test you can swap out something you actually own, and not have to interfere with `dayjs` at all:

```js
import { howSoonIsNow } from './path/to/noTimeLikeThePresent';

jest.mock('./path/to/noTimeLikeThePresent');

howSoonIsNow.mockReturnValue(new Date(2020, 8, 12));
```

Now if a new version of `dayjs` changes in a way that breaks your use of it, your tests will fail and tell you as much. Or if you swap to a different time library ([here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67317078/3001761) an example using Moment) you don't have to rewrite all of your tests, so you can be confident you've swapped over correctly.

Also FWIW I don't rate snapshot testing in general - it just becomes change detection, failing for irrelevant changes and encouraging people to ignore the test results and blindly recreate the snapshots if anything fails. Test based on the *behaviour* you want to see from your components.

Comment: Totally agree on the last comment, snapshot testing tends to do more harm to be honest.

Comment: What if you want to unit test your `howSoonIsNow` function. You would still need to mock dayjs

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa `howSoonIsNow` doesn't depend on `dayjs` at all. It's also trivial enough that you could reasonably decide it doesn't need testing at the unit level at all. The point is to invert the dependency on _time_, to make the code around it more testable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
jest.mock('dayjs/plugin/utc', () => ({
  default: jest.requireActual('dayjs/plugin/utc'),
}));
```

It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Mock dayjs like you wish and don't forget to set the static function as follows:

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";

jest.mock('dayjs', () =>
  jest.fn((...args) =>
    jest.requireActual('dayjs')(
      args.filter((arg) => arg).length > 0 ? args : '2020-08-12'
    )
  )
);

dayjs.extend = jest.fn();
```