# Moment gives a TypeError when testing with Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-typescript

I get an error while Unit Testing with Jest in React with TypeScript.

I don't get the error while testing if I change the original import in the component to `import * as moment from 'moment';` but, React throws a `Uncaught TypeError: moment is not a function` if I change the import.

While running the tests with Jest, I get this error:

```
● ChartCard › renders chart card with correct data
TypeError: (0 , moment_1.default) is not a function
```

This is part of my code:

```
import moment from 'moment';
moment(run.time_slice).format('ddd hh:mm');
```

Here is my Unit Test

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { ChartCard } from '@/views/Dashboard/Reports/ChartCard';
import { ChartDataType } from '../types';

describe('ChartCard', () => {
  const mockData: ChartDataType = {
    xData: [
      { total_count: 30, success_count: 20, failed_count: 10, time_slice: '2022-01-01T00:00:00Z' },
      { total_count: 30, success_count: 20, failed_count: 10, time_slice: '2022-01-01T00:00:00Z' },
    ],
    yDataPoints: ['total_count'],
    xDataPoints: ['time_slice'],
    yLabels: { success_count: 'Label 1', failed_count: 'Label 2' },
    yData: [
      { total_count: 30, success_count: 20, failed_count: 10, time_slice: '2022-01-01T00:00:00Z' },
      { total_count: 30, success_count: 20, failed_count: 10, time_slice: '2022-01-01T00:00:00Z' },
    ],
    backgroundColors: { success_count: 'red', failed_count: 'blue' },
  };

  it('renders chart card with correct data', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(
      <ChartCard
        data={mockData}
        tooltipLabel='Tooltip Label'
        cardTitle='Card Title'
        tooltipPosition='top'
        chartEmptyText='No Data found'
      />,
    );
    expect(getByText('Card Title'));
  });
```

Comment: You should mock moment js within the test environment in order to avoid brittle tests. Mind reproducing in jsfiddle or any similar platform

Comment: Counterpoint to ^: you shouldn't mock what you don't own. For test reproducibility, do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67317078/3001761).