How to handle external dependencies like Moment.js in unit tests for stub implementation?
I am currently learning unit testing in JavaScript, particularly focusing on stubs, from "The Art of Unit Testing". The author talks about making code more testable by removing dependencies, but I’m confused about how to apply this concept when using stubs with external dependencies like moment().
Here’s my situation: I have a password verification function that throws an error if it’s called on a weekend. There is also a wrapper function, verifyPasswordForCurrentDay, which uses moment().day() to get the current day of the week:
const SUNDAY = 0, SATURDAY = 6;

const verifyPassword = (input, rules, currentDay) => {
  if ([SATURDAY, SUNDAY].includes(currentDay)) {
    throw new Error("It's the weekend!");
  }
  // more code here...
  return [];
};

const verifyPasswordForCurrentDay = (input, rules) => {
  const currentDay = moment().day();
  return verifyPassword(input, rules, currentDay);
};

I’ve been able to test the verifyPassword function using a stub, passing the day of the week as a parameter. Here’s the test:
describe("verifier", () => {
  test("on weekends, throws exceptions", () => {
    expect(() => verifyPassword("any input", [], SUNDAY)).toThrow(
      "It's the weekend!"
    );
  });
});

However, I’m having trouble testing verifyPasswordForCurrentDay, as it has a dependency on moment().day(). In The Art of Unit Testing, the author suggests removing dependencies to make code testable.
I’m also concerned that we’ve merely moved the problem up one level. verifyPasswordForCurrentDay still has an external dependency (moment), making it difficult to test. By using parameter injection, we make a testable function (verifyPassword), but we’re only moving the problem up a level, meaning the wrapper function (verifyPasswordForCurrentDay) becomes untestable or harder to test. Is this correct?

Invert the dependency. Rather than calling moment() in the function, have it take a factory to create a moment object (or even the day string, decoupling you further from the dependency). Then you can override that factory for testing. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67317078/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65130857/3001761

@jonrsharpe, thank you so much for your response! I have another question about unit testing. Does unit testing sometimes lead to improvements in our production code? For example, when we try to make our code more testable or catch bugs before they reach production, it can lead to changes that improve the design. In other words, is unit testing more than just about testing—can it also help us refactor and improve the design of our production code? Is that correct?

I certainly think so, especially when you test-drive development; I've written a bunch about it on https://blog.jonrshar.pe/tag/javascript.html
