# Set moment timezone in Jest tests

Tags: javascript, date, mocking, jestjs, momentjs

I have the util function that is parsing given date (i.e. '2019-01-28') in specific date format and then using `momentJS` retrieving beginning of that day and converting it to ISO date format:

**dates.js**

```
import moment from 'moment'

export const getApiDateFormat = (date, dateFormat = getLocaleDateString()) =>
    moment(date, dateFormat)
      .startOf('day')
      .toISOString()
```

I would like to test this function using `Jest` and set the specific timezone for `moment` to use those tests independent of my location.

For now, I have:

**dates.test.js**

```
const formattedDate = '2019-01-27T23:00:00.000Z'

test('date in russian format - 28.01.2019', () => {
      const russianDateFormat = 'DD.MM.YYYY'
      expect(getApiDateFormat('28.01.2019', russianDateFormat)).toEqual(
        formattedDate,
      )
    })
```

since I'm currently located in `Europe/Warsaw` timezone. How to make this test location independent?

I've tried to use `jest.mock` to replace `moment` used by `getApiDateFormat` by `moment.tz.setDefault("America/New_York")`, however, all my attempts have failed since they have no influence on `moment` lib imported by `getApiDateFormat`.

How to solve such a problem and test it properly?

Comment: Maybe [How to mock moment.utc() for unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46891897/4131048) can be useful to you.

Comment: If anyone needs a solution for that problem I can recommend timezone-mock lib - https://www.npmjs.com/package/timezone-mock.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `TZ` env var...

You can prepend to your `package.json` so all machines run with the same timezone like so:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "TZ=UTC jest",
    "coverage": "TZ=UTC jest --coverage"
  },
```

Comment: Does it work on Windows machines? I tried this but It didn't work.

Comment: @DanielNguyen no, this one doesn't work on Windows in Node versions lower than 17. More info here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4230

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to set that timezone for all test files, setting the TZ environment should be enough but if you're looking for setting the timezone for a single test file, the following should be enough

```js
import moment from 'moment-timezone'
moment.tz.setDefault('America/New_York')
```

https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone/

Comment: This works for test cases in windows and there is no need to add env var.

Comment: Ensure to use `import moment from moment-timezone` in your main code too lol. I was using `moment` at first