# Can I assign what "now" is using Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, momentjs

I'm using moment.js and I want to write a test that says, "If you do not pass in a date, it returns `now()`".  The problem is, every time the test runs, `now()` will be a different result.  In other libraries, you can set what `now()` will return for testing purposes.  Does moment.js provide a way to do that?  I've been googling and not finding any results that say whether or not you can do this.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a exact duplicate, but I think [How to mock moment.utc() for unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46891897/4131048) is related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timekeeper (https://www.npmjs.com/package/timekeeper) fills this exact need.

It overrides the date constructors (which moment uses under the hood) so it will work for moment as well.

You can do the following:

```
const timekeeper = require('timekeeper');

const freezeDate = new Date();
timekeeper.freeze(freezeDate);

// in your test
expect(result).to.equal(freezeDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the time source (which basically overrides the implementation with a new `Date.now`) before each test by doing the following [from the official `momentjs` docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/now/). This returns the number of milliseconds since unix epoch time (1/1/1970).

```
moment.now = function () {
    return +new Date();
}
```