# Is there an option in javascript / momentjs to set today's date?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to set today's date to the end of the month (for example), for manual testing purposes. I am using MomentJS, so if there's any way in MomentJS or in javascript environment to set today's date globally - id like to know. Thank you.

Comment: You want to set the system clock?  Or just in the browser?

Comment: JavaScript in the browser relies on the system clock. You cannot change that from browser-based JavaScript.

Comment: Im using only to momentJS, so if settomg the brower clock will help - so its also ok

Comment: Then change your system clock to the time you want.

Comment: You can probably find an answer here: [How to mock moment.utc() for unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46891897/4131048)