# How do you mock just certain parts of a module with jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, momentjs

I've built a calendar around `moment.js` and I'm working on unit tests right now.

The first problem I solved was how the date will change when the tests run, so I've been able to lock down the moment using [this guidance](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/mocking-moment-js-in-jest-a-simple-one-line-solution-61259ffaaa2).

Currently, I'm stuck on an error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'weekdaysShort' of undefined"

My code has a line: `const dateHeaders = moment.weekdaysShort();`

By implementing the mocked `moment().format()`, I've essentially lost the rest of the library.

**My immediate question** is how I can set up jest to let me return the array that you get from `moment.weekdaysShort();`

**My larger question** is whether I've gone down the wrong path and should come up with another strategy.

**Things I've tried with unsuccessful results**

1. Manually adding in the `weekdayShort` function:

```
const mockMoment = function() {
  return {format: '2016–12–09T12:34:56+00:00'}
};

mockMoment['weekdaysShort'] = () => ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues']; // etc etc etc

jest.mock('moment', () => mockMoment);
```

2. Assembling a manual mock in a `__mocks__` folder.  I didn't go too far down this path because it started to feel like I'd have to copy/paste the entire Moment.js library into the mock.  And while it'd be cool to figure out how they do what they do, that's a project for another day.
3. `jest.spyOn` - doesn't work because I'm not spying on a module.

At this point, I'm considering abandoning the `Moment` function for an array passed in through props.  And while I'm confident that'll get me past this problem, it feels like I'm gonna hit another roadblock quickly afterwards.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have a look at [How to mock moment.utc() for unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46891897/4131048) to see an example of mocking momentjs output for testing.

Answer (score 7):

Just found out the pattern I commonly use was provided in a [2016 github thread](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-265074320) and, in all honesty, that's probably where I found it even though I don't specifically remember it :)

```
jest.mock('moment', () => 
  const original = jest.requireActual('moment');
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: {
       ...original,
       ...just the parts you want to mock
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

MomentJS and Jest don't play well together.  The `requireActual` method will be awesome, but even providing the following yielded a component that wouldn't render.

```
jest.mock('moment', () => 
  const original = jest.requireActual('moment');
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: {
       ...original,
    }
  }
);
```

Ultimately, I was able to lock the date down to a single moment by mocking the Javascript Date object, on which MomentJS builds all of this functionality.

```
describe('Calendar', () => {
  let dateNowSpy;

  beforeAll(() => {
    dateNowSpy = jest.spyOn(Date, 'now').mockImplementation(() => 1487076708000);
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    dateNowSpy.mockRestore();
  });

  it('does things, () => {
    // all the things!
  }
}
```

Comment: moment additionally exports stuff in a namespace.  In your first example, you need to spread `original` above `default` and overwrite `default` as needed.