# Jest - restore original moment function in one test

Tags: jestjs, momentjs

How can I restore or implement mock in one test? I have a function:

```
const parser = (data)=>{
    const now = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');

    //more implementation

    const parsedDate = moment(dateFromData).format('DD-MM-YYYY')

    return {
        date: isDateFromDataExists ? now : parsedDate
    }

}
```

And now I would like to test my function. When `isDateFromDataExists` is true I would like to return current year (which should be mocked), but when `isDateFromDataExists` is false I would like to return `parsedDate`.
When I mocked globally

```
jest.mock('moment', () => () => ({format: () => '01-01-2020'}));
```

I can't "unlock" in one test.

How can I do this with Jest?

**====EDIT====**

**This is my code.**

```
const myParser = (single) => {
  const obj = {};

  const now = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY");

  obj.availableFrom = get(single, 'FreeFrom', '') !== '' ? moment(get(single, 'FreeFrom'), 'YYYY-MM-DD').format("DD-MM-YYYY") : now;

   return obj;
}
```

**This is my tests**

```
test('Return correct json when FreeFrom is empty', async () => {
    const xmlData = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './testData/1.xml'), 'utf8');
    var jsonObj = parser.parse(xmlData, options, true);

    const result = require('./testData/1.json');
    expect(myParser(jsonObj)).toEqual(result);
});

test('Return correct json when FreeFrom is available', async () => {
    const xmlData = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './testData/2.xml'), 'utf8');
    var jsonObj = parser.parse(xmlData, options, true);

    const result = require('./testData/2.json');
    expect(myParser(jsonObj)).toEqual(result);
});
```

I have to cover two test cases.

1. When FreeFrom is not empty string then convert value with moment. Then format to my format.
2. When FreeFrom is empty string then use current date with moment. Then format to my format.

In case **2.** I would like to mock current date to make tests independent of system date.

Comment: See if [How to mock moment.utc() for unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46891897/4131048) can be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments [check related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46891897/4131048)

Here's how you could implement it

```js
let dateFromData = null;
let isDateFromDataExists = null;

const parser = (data) => {
  const now = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');

  const parsedDate = moment(dateFromData, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('DD-MM-YYYY')

  return {
    date: isDateFromDataExists ? now : parsedDate
  }

}

const {
  core: {
    beforeEach,
    describe,
    it,
    expect,
    run
  },
} = window.jestLite;

describe("parser", () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    const currentTimestamp = moment().valueOf();

    moment.now = jestLite.core.jest.fn().mockReturnValue(currentTimestamp);
  });

  it("return current date when isDateFromDataExists is true", () => {
    isDateFromDataExists = true;
    const currentDate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');

    expect(parser().date).toBe(currentDate);
  });

  it("return parsed date when isDateFromDataExists is false", () => {
    isDateFromDataExists = false;
    dateFromData = "02-01-2003";
    expect(parser().date).toBe(dateFromData);
  });
});

run().then(result => {
  console.log(result);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jest-lite@1.0.0-alpha.4/dist/core.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Add `beforeEach` callback code before this line `var jsonObj = parser.parse(xmlData, options, true);` and i think it should be fine