# Can't mock date/moment in Jest

Tags: mocking, jestjs, momentjs

I am writing a test for a Vue method that uses moment to format and return today's date, and am trying to mock moment in my test so that "today's date" isn't always changing when I run my tests.

My method is

```
return `Today is ${moment().format('MMM Do YY')}`;
```

I read that because Moment relies on Date.now() anyways, you can just mock that.

In my test I have:

```
test('prints out daily greeting', () => {
    Date.now = jest.fn(() => 1587893830000);

    expect(GreetingPage.methods.greetingMessage.toBe('Today is May April 26th 2020');
  });
```

However, when I run my test, it always receives 'undefined' instead of the date. I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: See if [How to mock moment.utc() for unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46891897/4131048) can be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your case and you should be able to do something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-mock-moment-kkkzk?file=/src/index.spec.js) using `spyOn` and `mockReturnValue` like so:
`jest.spyOn(Date, "now").mockReturnValue(new Date(1587893830000).getTime());`

Furthermore, your format input `'MMM Do YY'` doesn't match your expected output `'May April 26th 2020'` which should be `'Apr 26th 20'`.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing the same thing. I think that works best. Tx